# Installing Windows Server in Hyper-V on client

Tags: windows-8.1, hyper-v, windows-server-2012

Can Windows Server 2008 or 2012 R2 be installed in Hyper-V running on Windows 8.1 Pro?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot install any version of Windows Server in Hyper-V running on Windows 8.1. Client versions of Windows only allow Client Guest OS (XP/Vista/7/8) and Server versions of Windows only allow Server Guest OS (2008/2012).

Fore more details, see: [Supported Windows Guest Operating Systems for Hyper-V in Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn792027.aspx)